# Why does perl ignore extra characters in my regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I have this line in bash:

`echo "a=-1"|perl -nle 'if (/.*=[0-9]*/){print;}'`

and get:

`a=-1`

Wait..I didn't say perl should match on the `-`.  I made a minor change to:

`echo "a=-1"|perl -nle 'if (/.*=[0-9]*$/){print;}'`

and it correctly ignores the line.  Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[0-9]* can match the empty string.  When you anchored to the end of the string, you prevented this empty match.

You probably want to say [0-9]+ to  mean "at least one digit".

Answer (score 6):

You might find it useful, while developing a regex, to print *only the part of the string that the regex actually matched*, instead of the entire line.  This will give you better insight into what your regex is doing.  You can do this with the special `$&` variable.  So instead of:

```
echo "a=-1"|perl -nle 'if (/.*=[0-9]*/){print;}'
```

use

```
echo "a=-1"|perl -nle 'if (/.*=[0-9]*/){print $&;}'
```

You will now get different output:

```
a=
```

And this new information may give you a head start in understanding how your regex is [mis]behaving with regards to the input data.

Answer (score 5):

The first example, you say that [0-9] can happen "*" times, that means zero or more (so it matches only the "=".  When you added that "$" it doesnt match anymore because it doesn't end after the [0-9].